# Define type for higher order function

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have below controller which is a higher order method,

```
const CourseController = {
  createCourse:
    ({ CourseService }) =>
    async (httpRequest) => {
      const course = await CourseService.doCreateCourse(httpRequest.body);
      return {
        statusCode: 201,
        body: {
          data: course
        }
      };
    },
}
```

Below is my type definition for controller return type.

```
/**
 * ControllerResponse
 * @typedef {Object} ControllerResponse
 * @property {Number} statusCode
 * @property {{ data: (Object | Array )}} body
 */
```

How do I define type for `createCourse` so that It returns `ControllerResponse` type?

***Update:***

Tried something like below. It works, but return type from the controller doesn't seem right.
When I mark it async,

```
@returns {async function(ExpressRequest): Promise.<ControllerResponse> }
```

I loose the type definition.

```
  /**
   * Handle creating a new course.
   * @async
   * @method
   * @param {{ CourseService  }} requestBody - Request Body
   * @returns {function(ExpressRequest): Promise.<ControllerResponse> } Course
   */
```

Comment: You've tagged this typescript when it appears you are asking about jsdoc

Answer (score 0):

It seem to work now,

```
  /**
   * Handle creating a new course.
   * @async
   * @method
   * @param {{ CourseService  }} requestBody - Request Body
   * @returns {Promise<function(ExpressRequest): Promise.<ControllerResponse>> }
   */
```